# How to write ORDER BY clause to return results with entries in both tables first?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**table:** ads
**fields:** id, price

**table:** cars
**fields:** id, ad_id, year

I want to be able to order the results by cars.year - however not all results will have an entry in the cars table, i.e. some results may only have entries in ads.

At the moment results without entries are being returned first by my "order by cars.year ASC, ads.price ASC" clause, I want results that don't have cars entries to appear after the results that do.

Any ideas how I can with this ORDER BY clause?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the field of sorting in ads

Comment: Then why does it say `order by cars.price DESC` in the question?

Comment: cars doesn't even have a price field according to your definition of the tables

Comment: @mark, nathan - to many hours looking at this have me mis-typing, just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ORDER BY clause similar to the following:

```
ORDER BY cars.id IS NULL ASC, cars.year ASC, ads.price ASC
```

This will put the rows where `cars.id` is not null first, sorted by descending price. Then afterwards will be the rows where `cars.id` is null, also sorted by descending price.

It's not completely clear to me from your question what ordering you want, so you may have to adjust this answer slightly to fit your needs.

Comment: +1. But  it probably should be `cars.id IS NULL ASC`, not `DESC` (he wants them to appear after the ads that have cards)

Answer (score 0):

```
order by ifnull(year,'1/1/2099'), price
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put the records with entries in both tables last?

Comment: [IsNull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) behaves a little different in MySQL. You'd want to use [Coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) here instead.

Comment: @joe, using ifnull instead once i realized it was mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use two select commands .. first one selects values that have entries and orders them .. the second one selects the values with no entries and orders them then join the results ..